# UISwitch().setOn does not work (seemly)

Tags: ios, ios9, uiswitch, touch-id

here is the uiswitch valueChange action

```
@IBAction func swichTouchIdState(sender: UISwitch) {
    print("newState:\(sender.on)")
    if sender.on == false {
        AuthenticationSetter.touchIdAuthentication() {
            isSuccess, error in
            if isSuccess == true {
                AuthenticationSetter.setAuthenticationSwitchUserDefault(false)
            } else {
                sender.setOn(true, animated: true)
            }
            if let laError = error as? LAError {
                print("error happened in authenticating: \(laError)")
                switch laError {
                case .AppCancel:
                    print("App Cancel")
                    self.touchIdSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
                    break
                case .SystemCancel:
                    print("System Cancel")
                    self.touchIdSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
                    break
                case .UserCancel:
                    print("User Cancel")
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.touchIdSwitch.setOn(true, animated: false)
                    }
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            } else {
                print("no error")
            }
        }
    } else {
        AuthenticationSetter.setAuthenticationSwitchUserDefault(true)
    }
}
```

and here is the AuthenticationSetter.touchIdAuthentication function

```
class func touchIdAuthentication(doAfterAuthentication: (Bool, NSError?) -> Void) {
    let laContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    if laContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        laContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "TouchID Authentication", reply: doAfterAuthentication)
    } else {
        print("device don't support touchId")
    }
}
```

and when I touch cancel at the touchid window， the "User Cancel" is printed but the switch doesn't become on.

I create a new demoViewController that has a UISwitch and a button

when the buttonpressed this function is called : `demoSwitch.setOn(demoSwitch.on, true)`

and It run just well!!!!  can any ios master help me!

Comment: Is `self.touchIDSwitch` the same as the `sender`? In other words, are you just trying to turn the switch back on when the user turns it off?

Comment: yes yes, I just want to do that because when the user is trying to closing the switch, and failed in touchid authentication, the switch can return to the state before it was touched

Comment: and yes, self.touchIDSwitch is the same as the sender